# Informix OVER (PARTITION BY) like function

Tags: informix

I am new to the forum and new to informix. I have worked mostly with MSSQL in the past.

Now I have an informix DB with a table that has dupliate entries with a different timestamp.

I need to get the latest records for each key...

i.e.

```
accountnumber, datetime, column1, column2, column3
00001, 2017-01-01 01:01:01, 1, 1, 1
00002, 2017-01-01 01:15:01, 1, 1, 1
00003, 2017-01-01 01:37:01, 1, 1, 1
00001, 2017-01-01 01:48:02, 2, 2, 2
00002, 2017-01-01 02:07:02, 2, 2, 2
00003, 2017-01-01 02:13:12, 2, 2, 2
00001, 2017-01-01 02:50:10, 3, 3, 3
00002, 2017-01-01 03:25:42, 3, 3, 3
00003, 2017-01-01 04:15:32, 3, 3, 3
```

I I need a query which would produce the following results

```
accountnumber, datetime, column1, column2, column3
00001, 2017-01-01 02:50:10, 3, 3, 3
00002, 2017-01-01 03:25:42, 3, 3, 3
00003, 2017-01-01 04:15:32, 3, 3, 3
```

I made this work using something like "datetime>( (SELECT max(datetime) - X UNITS MINUTE)" because the time diff is usually a few minutes but this is not very reliable and will run into an issue where the query will wither return duplicate data or will not return all the data.

In MSSQL this could be done with OVER (PARTITION BY). I have no idea how to do this in informix.

Any help would be appreciated.

Kenan

Comment: Which version of Informix are you using?  In 12.10, you should be able to use the same notation as in MS SQL Server.  If you're on an earlier version, you have to work hard.

Comment: Thanks Jon. I made it work with some nested queries... not very elegant but works.